# Selecting the innerHTML of two <td>'s inside a <tr id="blahblahblah">

Tags: javascript, html

Ok, so I've got an onclick event (CF-D07 is an example, these are generated programmatically based on a MySQL database):

```
<input type="checkbox" onclick="var nameUpdate = 'CF-D07';
datechange();" id="CF-D07">
```

So then, under datechange(), I have this:

```
function datechange() {
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject

("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

  }

document.body.getElementsByTagName("tr").getElementsById(nameUpdate);

   // This section isn't done yet.

   // var url = "changedate.psp"
   // var params = "user=" + nameUpdate

   // xmlhttp.open("GET", url + "?" + params,false);
   // xmlhttp.send();
   // xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML;

}
```

The important part of this is this part of the code:

```
document.body.getElementsByTagName("tr").getElementsById(nameUpdate);
```

How do I make it so that I get all of the elements with the  tag, that then have the id of nameUpdate, based on the onclick event? And then after that, how do I select the innerHTML of the first two 's in the  and put it into separate variables?

Comment: ID is unique. Therefore, "all of the elements with the tag, that then have the id of nameUpdate" is invalid.

Comment: What @GeorgeCummins said. 'getElementById' is singular; you need to use 'getElementsByClassName'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you should never have more than one element with the same ID on any page. If you need to classify html elements, use the `class` attribute.

To get the inner html of elements, you can use aptly named `innerHTML` property of the DOM element:

```
function datechange(nameUpdate) {
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();  
    } else {
        // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

    }

    // document.body.getElementsByTagName("tr").getElementsById(nameUpdate);
    var trs = document.getElementByClassName(nameUpdate);

    for(var i = 0, len = trs.length; i < len; ++i) {
        var html = tr.innerHTML;
        // Do what you need to with HTML
    }
}
```

With the above code, your original HTML snippet could look like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" onclick="datechange('CF-D07')">
```

This also assumes you'd have a `tr` somewhere that looks something like this:

```
<tr class="CF-D07">
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
</tr>
```

To access the `<td>` elements of a given `<tr>`, you can use the `children` property for all child elements, or you can use `getElementsByTagName` directly on the `tr` element:

```
var tr = ... // get the TR somehow
var tds = tr.getElementsByTagName('td');
var allHTML = "";
for(var i = 0, len = tds.length; i < len; ++i) {
    allHTML += tds[i].innerHTML;
}

// Do something with allHTML, which is the inner html of all tds put together
```

Comment: That should be 'getElementsByClassName', not 'getElementsByClass'.

Comment: Now if I wanted to take every td except the last one, would I put in len = tds.length - 1 ? Or is there a different syntax?